Jenkins automatic deployment
Is there a way to have a job to be built automatically while picking a variable for the microservice that needs to be built..
I want Jenkins to deploy automatically depending on the folder that was changed in the Git repository.. But this does not seem to work.. Do you guys have any idea ?
for example, i tried:
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Starting build ms service .'
            }
        }

        stage('microservice1') {
            when { changeset "*/microservice1/**"}
            steps {
                echo "====microservice1===="
                build job: '/APP/Microservices/Microservice_Integ/develop', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'appName', value: 'microservice1']], wait: false, propagate: false
            }
        }
        stage('microservice2') {
            when { changeset "*/microservice2/**"}
            steps {
                echo "====microservice2===="
                build job: '/APP/Microservices/Microservice_Integ/develop', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'appName', value: 'microservice2']], wait: false, propagate: false
            }
        }
    }
}

I was expecting for Jenkins to detect the folder that was changed in Git and then build the microservice corresponding to that folder..

I would expect the same thing. Can you tell us what actually happens? Maybe add a build log to your question.
